# Postgres cannot find enum type if prepended by schema name

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I receive the following error when performing a query in Postgres:

column "action" is of type schemaname.enum_rights_actions but expression is of type enum_rights_actions

Is this a schema related issue?

`alter database postgres set search_path=schemaname` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround. 
The original definition of the table was:

```
CREATE TABLE rights_history(
    ...,
    action schemaname.enum_rights_actions,
    ...
);
```

I changed the definition of the table by removing the prepended schema name:

```
CREATE TABLE rights_history(
    ...,
    action enum_rights_actions,
    ...
);
```

That helped.
DDL SQL was generated using pgmodeler.

Comment: I'm not sure you've fixed the underlying problem. I suspect you've got two copies of the enum type in different schemas. The "other" one is in your search_path (maybe in public?)

Comment: `\dn` lists only one schema in my database. I have dropped public schema.